# MongoDB C# How to delete nested record

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have the following structure

```
{
    "_id" : "68f77d83-7141-4867-a355-16eda3ebe470",
    "Roles" : [ 
        {
            "Id" : "0001010260",
            "RoleIds" : [ 
                "Customer", 
                "Admin"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I try to only delete one RoleId so "Customer" or "Admin".
I have two filters which I combine with AND.

```
FilterDefinition<RoleEntry> subFilter = Builders<RoleEntry>.Filter.Eq(p => p.Sub, _sub);
FilterDefinition<RoleEntry> idFilter = Builders<RoleEntry>.Filter.ElemMatch(p => p.Roles, r => r.Id == _role.Id);
```

I can delete the whole RoleIds element with.
I don't know how I get one level deeper.

Tried it with

```
UpdateDefinition<RoleEntry> updateDefinition = Builders<RoleEntry>.Update.Unset("Roles.$.RoleIds");
UpdateResult result = await _roleEntryConnector.RoleEntryCollection.UpdateOneAsync(andFilter, updateDefinition, null, cancellationToken);
```

But this removed the RoleIds completly.

Answer (score 1):

Wow yesterday tried for hours and now after posting the question I think I got it.

```
UpdateDefinition<RoleEntry> updateDefinition = Builders<RoleEntry>.Update.Pull("Roles.$.RoleIds", "Customer");
```